# draw an coloured rectangle in CPTAxisLabel (core-plot)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

What I want is to draw a small rectangle inside an CPTAxisLabel to display a colour, what I have all ready tried is to draw a rectangle in a layer and add it as sublayer, but it stretches the small sublayer all over the label and the text isn`t visible anymore, I also tried to make an CPTLegend and add it to the label but I did not found any method to position it in the right side of the label, it just sits in the center, I tried changing the legends position, frame, bounds, padding and nothing. Does anyone know a better way of adding a rectangle shape in an CPTAxisLabel and also keep the text in the label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some long researches I found [issue 266 in core-plot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=266) and it seems to be the problem I have with positioning a sublayer inside a `CPTAxisLabel`... I will keep waiting for a fix, but I don`t know if it will be solved soon.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a `CPTTextLayer` for the label's `contentLayer`. Use an image fill on the text layer that contains your rectangle. Make it a stretchable image and set the stretchable area to the right of the rectangle. Set the `paddingLeft` on the text layer to leave room for the rectangle to the left of the label text.

Comment: I tried this, and the problem is that if I add a sublayer on CPTTextLayer it resizes with the textLayer size and if I add padding for the sublayer, it changes the sublayer and the parent layer(CPTTextLayer), I also tried to make sublayer layer as : CPTTextLayer, CPTLayer, CALayer and no results....